# How to find all that has multiple relationships in many to many with Rails3 in a elegant way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User class with

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :forum_subscriptions
  has_many :forums, :through => :forum_subscriptions
```

And a Forum class with

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
```

I want to find all the users that are subscribed to forum "sport", forum "TV" and forum "Hobby"
What is the most elegant way to do it?

(I have a lot of ugly stuff in my mind :-)

Comment: Have you tried sketching this relationship? You may want to have users have forums through forum subscriptions. Right now it looks like circular and incomplete ownership.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I would use:

```
User.joins(:forums).where("forums.title IN (?)", %w(sport TV Hobby)).group("users.id")
```

I assumed the column for the forum's title is 'title'. Change it when you're using some other name. You can put this inside a nice scope inside the User Model to make it a bit more dynamic.

```
scope :subscribed_to, lambda { |forum_titles| joins(:forums).where("forums.title IN (?)", forum_titles).group("users.id") }
```

Now you can call this scope from inside the Controller or some other place:

```
User.subscribed_to(%w(sport TV Hobby)) # => Get all users that are subscribed to sport, TV and Hobby
User.subscribed_to(["sport", "TV", "Hobby"]) # => Does the same
User.subscribed_to(%w(Hobby)) # => Get all users that are subscribed to Hobby
User.subscribed_to("Hobby") # => Does the same
```

I assumed you have the following relationships:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :forum_subscriptions
  has_many :forums, :through => :forum_subscriptions
end
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :forum_subscriptions
  has_many :users, :through => :forum_subscriptions
end
class ForumSubscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :forum
end
```

Hope this is what you needed. :)

Comment: The IN makes it an **or** not an **and** :-(

Comment: Besides the group clause doesn't work out of the box with postgres, you have to add .select('users.id') somewhere. Something like  User.select('users.id').joins(:forums).where('users.id = 1').where('forums.id IN (1,2)').group('users.id')